# How to iteratively retrieve data from Firebase using Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 questions actually:

1. How do I iteratively get the names of all user names from first to last user?
2. How can I retrieve data from all the sibling nodes from one ID. Suppose I enter `xyz`, the query should return `number:99, car1`....etc.)

---

```
User1{
  name: xyz
  number: 99...
  car1{ regno: 123
        make: ghj   }
  car2{.....}
 }
User2{..... }
```

Comment: Hey! It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1>How do I iteratively get the names of all user names from first to last user?

```
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String names=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
     }
  }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
});
```

Here you have the snapshot at `Users` then you iterate inside each user and retrieve the names, assuming you have this database:

```
 Users
   user1
     name:xyz
   user2
     name: xziq
```

---

> Q2>How can I retrieve data from all the sibling nodes from one ID.(Suppose I enter xyz, the query should return number:99, car1....etc)

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
Query queries=ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("xyz");
queries.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

To retrieve the sibling nodes, then you need to use a query like `orderByChild("name").equalTo("xyz")` then attach a listener and retrieve the other nodes.